# Write the 2nd degree equation which have the following roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

$y_1$=${(x_1+x_2\varepsilon+x_3\varepsilon^2)}^3$

$y_2$=${(x_1+x_2\varepsilon^2+x_3\varepsilon)}^3$

where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ roots for the $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ and $\varepsilon$ = $\frac{-1}{2}$+$i$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. ${\varepsilon}^3=1$

Comment: Oh, just a second, I will check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The coefficients of the required equation are $${(x_1+x_2\varepsilon+x_3\varepsilon^2)}^3{(x_1+x_2\varepsilon^2+x_3\varepsilon)}^3$$ and $$-{(x_1+x_2\varepsilon+x_3\varepsilon^2)}^3-{(x_1+x_2\varepsilon^2+x_3\varepsilon)}^3.$$

They are symmetric functions of $x_1,x_2,x_3$. So it remains to express them by elementary symmetric polinomials $x_1+x_2+x_3=-a$, $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3=b$ and $x_1x_2x_3=-c$.

**Addendum:** It is known that the roots of a cubic equation are of the form:
$$x_1=u+v, \ \  x_2=u\varepsilon+v\varepsilon^2, \ \  x_3=u\varepsilon^2+v\varepsilon, $$
where $u,v$ are from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method .

Then $$x_1+x_2\varepsilon+x_3\varepsilon^2=u(1+\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2)+3v=3v$$
and similarly for $x_1+x_2\varepsilon^2+x_3\varepsilon$.

**$2$nd Addendum:** To calculate $u^3$ and $v^ 3$ one has to reduce the equation $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ to the form $y^3+py+q=0$ by the substitution $x=y-\frac{b}{3a}$. Then
$$
p=-\frac{a^2}{3}+b, \ \ \ q=\frac{2a^3}{27}-\frac{ab}{3}+c,
$$
$$u^3=-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{D}, \ \ v^3=-\frac{q}{2}-\sqrt{D}.$$

Hence $u^3+v^3=-q, \ u^3v^3=\frac{q^2}{4}-D=-\frac{p^3}{27}$ and the required equation is
$$y^2+27qy-p^3=0.$$

Comment: I thought there is a much simpler way.

Comment: @MFG Flay I think also, but I didn't found it.

Comment: @MFG Flay It seems I found it. I will add the answer.

Comment: thanks, dear Boris! And $x_1+x_2\varepsilon^2+x_3\varepsilon$ is  $3u$. Which is?

Comment: @MFG Flay Yes, certainly.

Comment: you, previously, wrote that 3v = 3b ... so that's why I thought that 3u also depends on a,b or c

Comment: @ MFG Flay Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: And $u^3v^3$ and $u^3+v^3$ have what values? Depending on $a,b,c$ coefficients

Comment: @ MFG Flay The explanation is too long, so I will again add it to the answer.

Comment: and the values of $p$,$q$ are known? And who is $D$ ? Thanks for your time and for your informations!

Comment: @ MFG Flay $p,q$ are expressed  in terms of $a,b,c$  as a result of the substitution $x=y-\frac{b}{3a}$. $D=\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}$

Comment: :( I can not follow your demonstration, you just said the results for u^3v^ and for u^3+v^3 directly, but I don't know all the steps that must be followed....

Comment: If you could, please wrote the whole demonstrations + every steps that, in the end, will give those formulas for D, and u & v. Also, the new variables p and q are having what values? The result should be an equation with the coefficients depending on a,b and c. Thank you!

Comment: @ MFG Flay I extended the answer. However just in case, check my calculations.